# C# - Difficulty with method involving array

Tags: c#

I am creating a program that intakes info for the number of visits on separate days to a centre. I am using an array to keep track of that info, but I also need to create a method that calls up the day with the least number of visits and then displays it in an output.

```
class ScienceCentreVisitation
{
    private string centreName;
    private string city;
    private decimal ticketPrice;
    private string[] visitDate;
    private int[] adultVisitors;
    private decimal[] totalRevenue;


    //constructors
    public ScienceCentreVisitation()
    {

    }

    public ScienceCentreVisitation(string cent)
    {
        centreName = cent;
    }

    public ScienceCentreVisitation(string cent, string cit, decimal price, string[] date, int[] visit, decimal[] rev)
    {
        visitDate = new string[date.Length];
        adultVisitors = new int[visit.Length];
        totalRevenue = new decimal[rev.Length];
        Array.Copy(date, 0, visitDate, 0, date.Length);
        Array.Copy(visit, 0, adultVisitors, 0, adultVisitors.Length);
        Array.Copy(rev, 0, totalRevenue, 0, rev.Length);
        centreName = cent;
        city = cit;
        ticketPrice = price;
    }

    //properties
    public string CentreName
    {
        get
        {
            return centreName;
        }
        set
        {
            centreName = value;
        }
    }

    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return city;
        }
        set
        {
            city = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal TicketPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return ticketPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            ticketPrice = value;
        }
    }

    public string[] VisitDate
    {
        get
        {
            return visitDate;
        }
        set
        {
            visitDate = value;
        }
    }

    public int[] AdultVisitors
    {
        get
        {
            return adultVisitors;
        }
        set
        {
            adultVisitors = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal[] TotalRevenue
    {
        get
        {
            return totalRevenue;
        }
        set
        {
            totalRevenue = value;
        }
    }

    //methods
    public decimal CalculateTotalRevenue()
    {
        decimal totalRev;

        int cntOfValidEntries;
        int total = 0;
        foreach (int c in adultVisitors)
            total += c;
        cntOfValidEntries = TestForZeros();
        totalRev = (decimal)total / cntOfValidEntries;
        return totalRev;
    }

    public int TestForZeros()
    {
        int numberOfTrueVisits = 0;
        foreach (int cnt in adultVisitors)
            if (cnt != 0)
                numberOfTrueVisits++;
        return numberOfTrueVisits;
    }

    public int GetIndexOfLeastVisited()
    {
        int minVisIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < adultVisitors.Length; i++)
            if (adultVisitors[i] < adultVisitors[minVisIndex])
                minVisIndex = i;
        return minVisIndex;
    }

    public int GetLeastVisited()
    {
        return adultVisitors[GetIndexOfLeastVisited()];
    }

    public string GetDateWithLeastVisited()
    {
        return visitDate[GetIndexOfLeastVisited()];
    }

    public int GetIndexOfMostRevenue()
    {
        int maxRevIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < totalRevenue.Length; i++)
            if (totalRevenue[i] > totalRevenue[maxRevIndex])
                maxRevIndex = i;
        return maxRevIndex;
    }

    public decimal GetMostRevenue()
    {
        return totalRevenue[GetIndexOfMostRevenue()];
    }

    public string GetDateWithMostRevenue()
    {
        return visitDate[GetIndexOfMostRevenue()];
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name of Centre: " + centreName +
               "\nCity: " + city +
               "\n Price of ticket: " + ticketPrice +
                "\nDate of Least One-Day Adult Visitors:\t\t" + GetDateWithLeastVisited() +
                "\nNumber of Least One-Day Adult Visitors:\t\t" + GetLeastVisited() +
                "\nDate of Most Total Revenue Collected:\t\t" + GetDateWithMostRevenue() +
                "\nHighest Total Revenue Collected:\t\t" + GetMostRevenue();
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
class ScienceCentreApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string centreName;
        string city;
        decimal ticketPrice = 0;
        int visitorCnt;
        string[] dArray = new String[5];
        int[] adultVisitors = new int[5];
        decimal[] totalRevenue = new decimal[5];
        char enterMoreData = 'Y';
        ScienceCentreVisitation scv;


        do
        {
            visitorCnt = GetData(out centreName, out city, out ticketPrice, dArray, adultVisitors, totalRevenue);
            scv = new ScienceCentreVisitation(centreName, city, ticketPrice, dArray, adultVisitors, totalRevenue);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(scv);

            Console.Write("\n\n\n\nDo you want to enter more data - " +
                          "(Enter y or n)? ");
            if (char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out enterMoreData) == false)
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - " +
                                    "No recorded for your respones");
        } while (enterMoreData == 'y' || enterMoreData == 'y');

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int GetData(out string centreName, out string city, out decimal ticketPrice, string[] dArray, int[] adultVisitors, decimal[] totalRevenue)
    {
        int i,
            loopCnt;

        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Name of Centre: ");
        centreName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("City: ");
        city = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Ticket Price: ");
        string inValue = Console.ReadLine();
        ticketPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(inValue);

        Console.Write("How many records for {0}? ", centreName);
        string inValue1 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(inValue1, out loopCnt) == false)
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - " +
                                "0 recorded for number of records");
        for (i = 0; i < loopCnt; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\nDate (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
            dArray[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            if (dArray[i] == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No date entered - " +
                                    "Unknown recorded for visits");
                dArray[i] = "Unknown";
            }
            Console.Write("Number of One-Day Adult Visitors: ");
            inValue1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(inValue1, out adultVisitors[i]) == false)
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid data entered - " +
                                    "0 recorded for adults visited");
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

I had it working before I made some changes to my program, but now it keeps coming up blank when I run it. Any idea why?

Comment: I think that if you post a lot of code and want everyone debug it for you, you should upload whole code. We can use it, run it, debug it by Visual Studio, instead of reading a lot of piece of code and debugging in mind. It will save up a lot of time for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having the complete code it's difficult to debug this for you.

But here's a suggestion that came up when I was reading the start of your question:
It seems like the basic gist would be to use a `Dictionary<DateTime, int>` which would store the number of visits for each day.

Then you can use a simple LINQ query to get the smallest value:
`dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).First()`

Of course, you can use a complex class in place of the `int` and store more data (location, price of admission for that day, adult visits, etc.).

```
class CenterVisitations
{
  internal int Visitations { get; set; }
  internal decimal TicketPrice { get; set; }
  internal string Location { get; set; }
  //add other stuff here, possibly create another class
  //to store TicketPrice, Location and other static center data
  //and create a reference to that here, instead of the above 
  //TicketPrice and Location...
}
```

Then you can define your dictionary like so:
`Dictionary<DateTime, CenterVisitations>`

And query it almost the same was as last time:
`dictionary.Order(kvp => kvp.Value.Visitations).First();`

Sorting and selecting would work the same way. Additionally you could add a `.Where` query to set a range of dates which you want to check:
`dictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Key < DateTime.Today && kvp.Key > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7))` will only look for the last weeks worth of data.

It also seems you're keeping your data in separate arrays, which means querying it is that much harder. Finally, consider converting dates into `DateTime` objects rather than strings.